Is it possible to use semantic ranker together with scoring profile?
We're using Azure Search feature in our app. We've enabled Semantic Ranker recently, but we've noticed that scoring profiles don't seem to work well with it.
While testing my search index with Search explorer in Azure, I've noticed that adding scoringProfile in parameters changes the order of results and modifies @search.score but does not modify @search.rerankerScore. But I also noticed that whenever I modify values in weights or functions of scoring profile, the value of @search.score changes but order stays the same. And that's the problem caused by semantic ranker - when it's enabled, search seems to sort results by @search.rerankerScore instead of @search.score.
I need both Semantic Ranker and Scoring Profiles to work together. I wanna make weights/functions more valuable in results. We are using freshness function and lack of that option gives us old results higher than new results. I want to be able to control the strength of semantic ranker and weights in freshness together, so I can balance it
Is there a way to increase importance of Scoring Profile in results while using Semantic Ranker at the same time?
I've already tried experimenting with weights, enabling and disabling scoring profile while semantic ranker was enabled.
Moreover, I found some conflicting informations, one of answers HERE says

We are looking into incorporating scoring profiles into the semantic feature, but don't have an actual date for this feature yet.

While in documentation there is information saying

You can use semantic ranker with scoring profiles.

So at this point I don't know where's the truth.
